# Paging Instagram location search API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get content from Instagram by location.

**My minimum timestamp is**: `1469023200` (20/07/2016 09:00 GMT -5)

**My maximum timestamp is**: `1469073600` (20/07/2016 23:00 GMT -5)

My strategy is to use `count=100` and receive the most recent `100` results.

After that, I will send another query, this time the maximum timestamp would be the lowest timestamp I received in my last query.

I will keep doing that until the lowest timestamp would be smaller than my `min_timestamp`.

**Example for first request:**

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=38.6226188&lng=-90.1928209&min_timestamp=1469023200&max_timestamp=1469073600&distance=500&count=100&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It looks like this approach works, although in none of the queries I receive `100` results.

It breaks down to few queries until I get to `min_timestamp`.
Weird. I would expect to receive 100 results in each query.

My next step was to break the time difference (15 hours) to an hourly interval, and keep querying Instagram until I reach the `min_timestamp`.

This is time I received twice as much content back.

**So my questions are as followed:**

1. Why doesn't Instagram return the full `count` value?
2. Theoretically - my first approach should have bring the full amount of content available for my query, does Instagram filter the content it returns?
3. This whole process doesn't feel right - since Instagram returns are not expectable. Maybe there is a better paging way for this type of query?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the queries do not return the actual count, my guess is that instagram is caching the count and sometimes some photos are deleted by users, so u may get less posts in response. I have implemented location search in https://www.picodash.com, I get some random count of posts for every API call, sometimes I get 1 or 2 posts per call.

Comment: might be, i still don't understand how could it be that query to the same location in the same time range will return different results.. how does Instagram decide what to return in an 8 hours range comparing to what it will return in a 1 hour range